# Rendering cell with value

Tags: java, swing

I have table in JTable. 2 columns with String and one with Integer. I'm trying to render (only integer column) cell if value is < 0. There is my code:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue,
                                               boolean aIsSelected, boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn) {

    if (aNumberValue == null) {
        return this;
    }
    Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
    );

    Number value = (Number) aNumberValue;
    if (value.doubleValue() < 0) {
        // do something with renderer
    } else {
        // do something with renderer
    }
    return this;
}
```

The problem is: I think that, that code try to check all of cells with String columns because I have error: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number` in that line: `Number value = (Number) aNumberValue;`. Could you tell me how to limit checking to only one column (id = 1)?

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Okay, I found how to limit my Render. Now I have code:

```
class TableRendererExample extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        int i = (int) value;
        System.out.println(value);
        c.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        return c;
    }
}
```

My question is... Why when I try to print value it is working but when I try to cast object (value) to integer I have exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. When I'm printing there are only values but problem is with casting...

Answer (score 2):

To add your renderer to a specific column in your table the code should be something like:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( customRenderer );
```

> I'm trying to render (only integer column) cell if value is < 0.

The easiest way to create your custom renderer is to do modify the value that is displayed:

```
class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer
    {
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public setValue(Object value)
    {
        Number number = (Number)value;

        if (number >= 0)
            number = null;

        super.setValue( value );
    }
}
```

You will also need to override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of  your TableModel or the JTable to return Integer.class and you must store Integer values in your TableModel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). The `TableToolTipsDemo` has an example of a table with different data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate based on the column index you get as a parameter.

Conceptually, it should work as follows

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue,
                                               boolean aIsSelected, boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn) {

    if (aColumn != MY_INTEGER_COLUMN_INDEX)
        // Use the default cell renderer component for
        // any column except for the Integer column
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
        );

    // special handling for the Integer column

    if (aNumberValue == null) {
        return this;
    }

    Number value = (Number) aNumberValue;
    if (value.doubleValue() < 0) {
        // do something with renderer
    } else {
        // do something with renderer
    }
    return this;
}
```

---

Concerning your edit, I can only restate [carmickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39749766/1314743):

- of course, if you want to cast your objects of that column to `Integer`, you have to ensure that the *table model* actually returns Integer values. The `DefaultTableModel`, per default, only returns Strings, as these are the value the user can type
- Read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the JTable documentation. Customizing JTables can be very complex, so you really have to understand how JTable works, how the models are related etc.

Comment: Okay but when it isn't myIntegerColumn, what if renderer object which I want to change?

Comment: “The problem is that you have to define a single TableCellRenderer for the complete table.” [No, you don’t.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setCellRenderer-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-)

Comment: Okay, so can you tell me what should I use to fix it to only one column?

Comment: @VGR whoops, missed that part. Corrected.

Comment: @J.Carrer Sorry, I do not understand your question. My outline of the code should work and gives you an immediate fix. Of course, you have to adapt it to the correct column number.